# Java Selenium webdriver is working, but highlighted in red

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a problem with my code.
It works although it shows red in vs code.
On the third import it says "package org.openqa.selenium does not exist(compiler.err.doesnt.exist)".

On WebDriver:
"cannot find symbol
symbol: class WebDriver
location: class Wait(compiler.err.cant.resolve.location)"

Should actually give a simple solution or?

Thanks already :,)

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Wait {
    public static void randomWait(WebDriver driver, int minWaitSec, int maxWaitSec) throws InterruptedException {
        int min = minWaitSec; 
        int max = maxWaitSec; 
        int randomWaitTime = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
        Thread.sleep(randomWaitTime);
    }
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

I am expecting the code as it is but without the red highlighting..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a maven Project , you need to declare Selenium Dependency in your project pom.xml as below

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Otherwise create a maven project in VS Code then add your class file tot he project and above dependency it should work fine